# Why would PHPMyAdmin connections fail when connections from the same server with the same credentials succeed?

Tags: linux, mysql, rackspace, rackspace-cloud

I have a site hosted on Rackspace Cloud. It runs Joomla 2.5, some test scripts, and PHPMyAdmin 4.1.6. Joomla runs off a database hosted in Rackspace Cloud. The host is `mysql50-[redacted].wc2.dfw1.stabletransit.com` I am able to take Joomla's settings and put them in a simple PHP script that runs mysqli_connect and read the database.

However, I am not able to get a PHPMyAdmin installation in a subfolder of the Joomla directory to connect. I PHPMyAdmin's setup and it generated this config file:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'description';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'mysql50-[redacted].wc2.dfw1.stabletransit.com';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

No other modification to PHPMyAdmin was done.

It seems to match the settings used by Joomla and the test scripts, but every time I connect, I receive a `#2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server` error. This error occurs no matter what username/password I use, hostname I use, or connection method/type I use. What is different about PHPMyAdmin that it fails to connect where Joomla and a simple mysqli_connect succeed?

Comment: Did you drop this generated config into the root folder of phpmyadmin?

Comment: Dear God. No, I thought it had to be in /config where it was generated. Works now. Feel free to make that an answer so I can accept!

Comment: Yeah, it can be confusing. A bit of google-fo showed me that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure the generated config file is in your root `phpMyAdmin` folder so it reads the proper file.